# Can conclude $\mu\left(A\right)=0$ and why?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\left\{ a_{n}\right\} $
  be a sequence of real numbers. Let $A$
  be the set of all real numbers $x$
  belonging to infinite open intervals $\left(a_{n},a_{n}+2^{-n}\right)$
 . Can conclude $\mu\left(A\right)=0$
  and why? ($\mu$
  is Lebesgue measure).

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Do you mean **all** open intervals?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: I don't think we can conclude that...I think we can conclude $\;\mu(A)\le 2\;$ ...

Comment: I don't get it (at least seeing the answers so far): Is $\;A\;$ the set of all those open intervals or the set of the *intersection* of all those open intervals??

Comment: @DonAntonio: I think it should be clear if it said "all" in the question.

Comment: Ok @John...so: which one do *you* understand it is? I understood it is the union of all those open sets...which, btw, can perfectly well be pairwise disjoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you familiar with the following result?

**Theorem**
If $\{E_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $m(E_1)<\infty$ and $E=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} E_n$, then $m(E)=\lim_{n\to\infty} m(E_n)$.

Answer (score 3):

Well $A \subseteq (a_n,a_n+\frac{1}{2^n})$ and

$\mu (a_n,a_n+\frac{1}{2^n})=\frac{1}{2^n}$ so $\mu(A) \leq \frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n$ thus $\mu(A)=0$

Comment: :) +1 Yes, this is easier than my answer!